# Problem with annotation procesor and Micronaut 2.0 transaction

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

I have a problem using the default transaction management that comes with Micronaut 2.0.
I know that I'm missing something but I don't know what.
I created a small example project [here](https://github.com/andcuevas/testing-micronaut-tx).

When I try to run the Application class I get the following error:

```
12:41:31.838 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: BeanDefinition.requiresMethodProcessing() returned true but method has no @Executable definition. This should never happen. Please report an issue.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanDefinition.requiresMethodProcessing() returned true but method has no @Executable definition. This should never happen. Please report an issue.
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.lambda$initializeContext$28(DefaultBeanContext.java:1569)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:272)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1566)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:220)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:2763)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:227)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:166)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:64)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:294)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:280)
    at prueba.jdbc.Application.main(Application.java:8)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I think that the problem is that I don't have the annotation processor micronaut-data-processor configured correctly, but I'm really lost here.

Comment: See https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/3721

Comment: Thanks @jeff, it looks similar. I'm going to open an issue in github.

Comment: This is more like a bug report, not a question.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug.I opened an issue in github and was marked as bug.

https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/3768